# Regex match only when capture group occurs last in string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a number of rows in a Pandas dataframe like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium', 
'k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium|s__Bifidobacterium_pseudolongum',
'k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium|s__Bifidobacterium_pseudolongum|t__GCF_000421365']})
```

I want to return the ones matching `g__` at the end of a string, e.g. using the following regex:

```
g__$
```

I expect to get this result:

```
k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium
```

But exclude these ones:

```
k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium|s__Bifidobacterium_pseudolongum
k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium|s__Bifidobacterium_pseudolongum|t__GCF_000421365
```

Comment: Something like `"\|g_.*$"`

Comment: Use `\|g__\w*$` or `\|g__[^|]*$`. Is the input a dataframe? Why do you say "rows"?

Comment: Yes the input is a dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df = df[df['Text'].str.contains(r'\|g__[^|]*$')]
```

The `\|g__[^|]*$` regex matches `|g__` and then zero or more chars other than `|` till the end of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pxhk3C/1).

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium', 
'k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium|s__Bifidobacterium_pseudolongum',
'k__Bacteria|p__Actinobacteria|c__Actinobacteria|o__Bifidobacteriales|f__Bifidobacteriaceae|g__Bifidobacterium|s__Bifidobacterium_pseudolongum|t__GCF_000421365']})
df = df[df['Text'].str.contains(r'\|g__[^|]*$')]
```